# Memory leak in javascript. Creating a new Object which have the socketObject

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-class

I have a similar function that receives socket object.

```js
class X {
  constructor (socketObject, callback) {
    this.socketObject = socketObject;
    callback(null, socketObject);
  }
}
const socketObject = {hello:'world'};
new X (socketObject, function (err, res) {
   if(!err)
      z(res)
})

function z(res){
  console.log(res);
}
```

Does it cause a memory leak of creating a new Class?

Comment: You're really not keeping the object returned by `new X(...)`?

Comment: Spelling matters in code, you've misspelled `construcor` and `sokcetObject`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes.

Comment: @CertainPerformance edited

Comment: Then why having a class at all?

Comment: @Jonas W i am doing code refactor

Comment: Thats not an argument. If you dont access the instance from somewhere else there is no benefit of a class over a simple closure.

Comment: *(picking up from [Jonas' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49400821/memory-leak-in-javascript-creating-a-new-object-which-have-the-socketobject/49400911?noredirect=1#comment85803200_49400821))* ...whereas there *are* unnecessary costs: 1. Extra code to write, read, and maintain. 2. Creating an object you don't need (although that's a very, very, very small cost not usually worth worrying about).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder it runs nodejs, and it is very frequent action, that's why keep the reference to the socket in this, creates a new namespace of socket without any declaration. Will it be destroyed after socket disconnected?

Comment: @EdwardGizbreht: There's no purpose whatsoever to the `X` class. Just pass the socket to the function. The function (and any functions it creates, such as event handlers) will retain a reference to the socket for as long as necessary, and (hopefully) no longer, allowing the socket to be garbage collected. The object created by `new X` is just wasted space, completely unneeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question's code has been edited. Re your initial code (but with the spelling corrections):

```
class X {
  constructor (socketObject, callback) {
    this.socketObject = socketObject;
    callback(null, null);
  }
}

new X (socketObject, function (err, res) {
  return;
})
```

No, no memory leak. There are two scenarios (which are really the same scenario):

Assuming you keep the object returned by `new X`, e.g.:

```
var x = new X (socketObject, function (err, res) {
  return;
})
```

...then the object `socketObject` (and now `x.socketObject`) refers to will be retained in memory as long as the object returned by `new X` is still referenced by something (`x`, in the above). When `x` goes out of scope or you assign it a different value, that object becomes eligible for garbage collection; and if there are also no other references to the socket object, so does it. (In your code, there's another reference to it though: The `socketObject` variable you pass into `new X`.)

If you *don't* keep the object returned by `new X`, then it's immediately available for garbage collection and, again, so is the socket object provided nothing else refers to it.

---

Regarding the new code in the question:

```
class X {
  constructor (socketObject, callback) {
    this.socketObject = socketObject;
    callback(null, socketObject);
  }
}
const socketObject = {hello:'world'};
new X (socketObject, function (err, res) {
   if(!err)
      z(res)
})

function z(res){
  console.log(res);
}
```

There's still no memory leak, provided your `socketObject` `const` goes out of scope at some point (if it's global, then in some sense there's a *very small* leak, since nothing can clear the reference it holds to the socket object, as it's a constant). In a comment you seem concerned about the function call; don't be, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Please, take a look, I changed the code. Now it will do another function. and i don't have 'var'

Comment: @EdwardGizbreht: Please don't edit questions such that they invalidate posted answers, it's one of the SO no-nos. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!